# git pull already up to date. Broke local files, need remote restore

Tags: git

I pushed a working code onto my remote branch `edge-tests`. I broke my local code and would like to revert the changes by

`git pull origin edge-tests`.

However, I do not see the error rectified and the git message is as follows:

`* branch              edge-tests -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.`

I did not push my remote file with local broken code.

Comment: You have all "patches" already downloaded and merged perhaps, but you need to reset your working copy to a clean state... try: "git reset --hard HEAD"

Comment: @Marcin git reset --hard edge-tests worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo yes it worked out with reset